# In php If and Else statements do not work with javascript location functions

Tags: javascript, php, html, position

I have a script in javascript and php that detects my position, the first part of the script works fine, after I would like if i set to a certain latitude and longitude value it do something, if latidudine and longitude are equal to preset values ​​for example, write "My House", otherwise write "out of my house". Even if I set the values ​​obtained from the script in the if the condition remains always false, perhaps because the script runs before the user gives consent to the location. Does anyone know how I could solve? Thanks in advance
Here my code:

```
<html>
<body>

  <SCRIPT>
  function showlocation(){
  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(callback);
  }

  function callback(position){
  document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
  document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
  }

  </SCRIPT>


  <?




  echo "<script>showlocation()</script>";

  $latitudine= "<span id=latitude></span><br>";
  $longitudine= "<span id=longitude></span>";

  echo "latitudine: ".$latitudine ."<br>";
  echo "longitudine: ".$longitudine."<br>";

  echo "latitudine: ".$latitudine ."<br>";
  echo "longitudine: ".$longitudine."<br>";
  if ($latitudine == "41.9473578" && $longitudine =="$longitudine")
  echo "My house";
  else echo "Out of my house"





  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: In order to check for your house you're probably going to need to compare your current lat/long against ranges. 0.001 degrees of latitude are roughly 100 yards. Your latitude is too precise and will most likely not match your measured position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP code run always in the server side and has not communication with JS code, that run in the browser.

You should make all the code in JS to make it work. This is a running example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showlocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(callback);
}

function callback(position){
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = latitude;
    document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = longitude;

    var location = 'Out of my house';

    if (latitude == '41.9473578') {
        location = 'My house';
    }

    document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = location;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="showlocation()">

    <label>latitudine</label>: <span id=latitude></span>
    <br />
    <label>longitudine</label>: <span id=longitude></span>
    <br /><br /><br />

    <label>Location</label>: <span id="location"></span>
</body>
</html>
```